# R: optim() when function has inputs in different formats

Tags: r, optimization

I have data

```
dat1 <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=rnorm(3))
dat2 <- data.frame(a=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,5),rep(3,4)), c=runif(12,1,50))
```

and a function that takes both data frames as inputs

```
foo <- function(dat1,dat2,par){
               if(par< 25){return(dat1$b*par)}
               if(par>=25){return(sum(dat2$c>par))}
       }
```

which might work if it was embedded in a loop over different values of `a`.

However, I would like to find the value of `par` that minimizes the output of `foo` across all values of `a`. The `optim()` funtion should be able to do just this, but my problem is that I need to pass it two dataframes of different dimensions. I suspect some form of list could help but wouldn't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the help documentation on `optim`,

> fn - A function to be minimized (or maximized), with first argument the vector of parameters over which minimization is to take place. It should return a scalar result.

Your function is not returning a scalar when `par < 25`. Since you are not changing the data.frames during optimization process, you do not have to pass in them again. Below is an example usage of `optim` in your case:

```
foo <- function(par) {
    if(par < 25) {
        return(sum(dat1$b*par))
    } else {
        return(sum(dat2$c>par))
    }
} 

optim(0, foo, method="Brent", lower=-1e6, upper=1e6)
```